# How to set PostgreSQL as the database for Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My professor said it would be wise to use PostgreSQL instead of SQLite in our project so that it would be easier to deploy to Heroku, but it seems that I didn't set up the database.yml properly.

Here's what I tried to do after I installed the Pg gem.  The default database.yml content was:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I decided to change the default adapter "sqlite3" to "postgresql", hence:

```
   default: &default
   adapter: postgresql
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000
```

but when I use scaffold I get the error:

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter but the gem is not loaded. Add 'gem pg' to your Gemfile and ensure its version is at the minimum required by active record
```

so I'm guessing that I need to put something like `gem 'postgresql'` in the gemfile. But the problem is I dont know the current version of PostgreSQL I have now so that I can put it on that line.

How do I know the current version of the PostgreSQL? Is this going solve my PostgreSQL setup for my project?

Comment: Look in Gemfile.lock - it will tell you what gems you've got and which version of each you're using.   You can run bundle update to get newer versions of your gems (although obvs you won't get newer versions than are allowed by any versions specified in your Gemfile)

Comment: I ran bundle install and changed the database used for Active Records from `sqlite3` to `postgresql` and it worked. thank you

Comment: By the way, you can use `rails new MyApp -d postgresql` and this will be done automatically. Heroku also has guides such as [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5)

Answer (score 1):

To use Postgres with Ruby on Rails you should follow these steps:

- add the pg gem to your *Gemfile* which is located in the root directory of your application
- run `bundle install`, which will install the gem and set its version and dependencies in your *Gemfile.lock*
- install and configure postgres in your computer
- configure the connection uri in `config/database.yml` by changing

  ```
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  ```

  to something like

  ```
  database: "postgres://username:password@hostname:port/database_name"
  ```

Comment: Installing pg gem part is correct however configuration of the database part is wrong. You should not and do not need to change anything in database configuration.

Comment: @jedi could you please elaborate on why it's not correct to change the database configuration

Comment: Oh well, not wrong, but I know there is plenty of documentation on how to configure your rails app with postgres to deploy it to Heroku like this one https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3 however from my experience I can tell this is not needed. I've never done this and my apps work fine on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile just add `pg` gem to your production group

`group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'
end`

Then run `bundle`